# Dynamic programming - Variant of shortest path problem

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

I have the following problem:

Given A directed graph $G = (V, E)$, a start vertex $s$ (in $V$), $length(u;v)$ (could be negative) for every edge $(u;v)$ in $E$ and a time $t(u;v)> 0$ that it takes to traverse the edge $(u; v)$, where each $t(u;v)$ is an integer in $[1,M]$. Finally, we are given a time bound $T$. 
The goal is to find the shortest path from $s$ to every other vertex, among paths that take time at most $T$ to traverse.
I have to use dynamic programming to devise an algorithm for this problem running in time polynomial in $n$ and in $M$.

In this case, since some length can be negative, I've thought to use Bellman algorithm or at least an extended version of this algorithm. I am looking for a path p such that it cost is

```
         Min{length(p): time(p) ≤ T }
```

could anyone help me with the pseudocode?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: consider a “layered network” with nodes $(u,t_u)$ and a directed edge from $(u,t_u)$ to $(v,t_v)$ if $(u,v) \in E$ and $t_v=t_u+t(u;v)$.

Comment: yes, that's what I was thinking. I was trying to implement it using the Bellman-Ford algorithm (for the presence of negative lengths); but I have doubts about it. Could you give me more clarification?

Comment: Because $t(u;v)>0$, the layered network is acyclic, so you can solve the DP with one pass.

Comment: ok so i have a DAG. But in this case I would have an order with respect to t, right?

Comment: Yes, each edge has $t_u<t_v$.

Comment: can it be implemented like this? Step 1: Initialize graph
for v in V
 d(v)=∞ (Initialize the distance to all vertices to infinity)
predecessor(v)∶= null         (set a null predecessor)
 d(s)= 0  (The distance from the source to itself is, of course, zero)

Step 2: Relax edges repeatedly
for k from 1 to n-1
 for each v in V in topological order with respect to t
  for each edge (u,v) with weight w in edges
   If d(v)>d(u)+w(u,v)
    then     d(v)=d(u)+w(u,v)
     predecessor(v)∶= u

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but you also need to account for $T$.

Comment: right..do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Include it in the definition of the layers.  Each node $(u,t_u)$ should have $t_u\le T$.

Comment: I've tried to implement it in the following way:                                                                                                                           for v in V
 d(v,0):=∞ (Initialize the distance to all vertices to infinity)
 D(s,0):= 0  (The distance from the source to itself is, of course, zero)
 for l∈R
  for each v in V
   D(v,l)≔D(v,l-1)
   for each (i,v)∈E
    k:= l - c_iv;
    D(v,l)≔min⁡{D(v,l),D(v,k)+t_iv}
   end
  end
  If D(d,l)≤T   return(b)
 end
end